# How do I relocate/disable GeckoDriver's log file in selenium, python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Ahoy, how do I disable GeckoDriver's log file in selenium, python 3?

If that's not possible, how do I relocate it to Temp files?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To relocate the *GeckoDriver* logs you can create a directory within your project space e.g. **Log** and you can use the argument **log_path** to store the *GeckoDriver* logs in a file as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe', log_path='./Log/geckodriver.log')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks! Under CentOS 7  I use this line: browser = webdriver.Firefox(log_path='/tmp/SISPI_logger_geckodriver.log')

Comment: Thanks, but what I don't understand is, where is this text? is this in a file? if yes, what file and where is that file?

Comment: Note that `log_path` is no deprecated in favor of `service_log_path`.

Answer (score 24):

using `WebDriver(log_path=path.devnull)` and `WebDriver(service_log_path=path.devnull` are both deprecated at this point in time, both result in a warning.

using a service object is now the prefered way of doing this:

```py
from os import path
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver

service = Service(log_path=path.devnull)
driver = WebDriver(service=service)

driver.close()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since the other answers are now depreceated

Comment: @aarondiel, thanks! Just 2023 Sep I received: DeprecationWarning: log_path has been deprecated, please use log_output
  serv = Service(new_driver_path, log_path=path.devnull)

Answer (score 8):

ref: [7. WebDriver API > Firefox WebDriver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver)

according to the documents, you can relocate it to Temp following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options$
import os

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=geckodriver_path, service_log_path=os.path.devnull, options=options)
```

Following argument are deprecated:

- firefox_options – Deprecated argument for options
- log_path – Deprecated argument for service_log_path

Comment: Where do I place (copy-paste) this code? (I gues not in notepad, but where?)

Comment: @tijnn for example, make a headless.py file and copy-past this code.

It required python and selenium module which can be get pip command. Is that your expected answer ??

Comment: this is more what I was looking for: https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the `service_log_path`, as of today the `log_path` is deprecated, example with pytest:

```
@pytest.mark.unit
@pytest.fixture
def browser(pytestconfig):
    """
    Args:
        pytestconfig (_pytest.config.Config)
    """
    driver_name = pytestconfig.getoption('browser_driver')
    driver = getattr(webdriver, driver_name)
    driver = driver(service_log_path='artifacts/web_driver-%s.log' % driver_name)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.set_window_size(1200, 800)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

No @hidehara, but I found a way how to do it. I looked up the file **init**  in the Selenium2Library directory. in my case: C:\Users\Eigenaardig\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary

there I added these 2 lines...

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\Eigenaar\eclipse-workspace\test\test\geckodriver.exe', log_path='./Log/geckodriver.log')
```

created the directory LOG (in Windows Explorer)

helaas, that started 2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

I added in a separate library (.py file)

which looks like this (for test purposes):

```
import time
import random

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\specimen\RobotFrameWorkExperienced\RobotLearn\Log\geckodriver.exe', service_log_path='./Log/geckodriver.log')

class CustomLib:
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'RobotLearn'

    num = random.randint(1, 18)

    if num % 2 == 0:
        def get_current_time_as_string(self):
            localtime = time.localtime()
            formatted_time = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", localtime)
            return formatted_time
    else:
        def get_current_time_as_string(self):
            localtime = time.localtime()
            formatted_time = time.strftime("%S%m%d%H%M%Y", localtime)
            return formatted_time
```

But now it opens up 2 instances,
1 runs correct,
1 stays open and does nothing furthermore.

help help.

Answer (score 0):

If it all for some reason does not work. (which was the case in our case).
then go to this (relative) directory:

C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\SeleniumLibrary\keywords\webdrivertools

there is a file called: webdrivertools.py
on line 157 you can edit

```
service_log_path='./robots/robotsiot/Results/Results/Results/geckoresults', executable_path=executable_path,
```

advantages:
#1 if you're using something like Github and you synchronize a directory then the log files are kept separate.
#2 the original file of the previous run gets overwritten
(if that is what you want, but in some cases that is exactly how you need it).

note: the section written above is in case you're using FireFox, if you are using another browser you'll have to edit it on a different line.
note2: this path overrides on a high level, so arguments in Eclipse->Robot framework will not have any effect anymore.

use this option with caution: it's sort of a last resort if the other options don't work!