# How do I disable geckodriver's log on Selenium (Python 3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver, gecko

I have not been able to find the answer to this.

This particular answer only tells we can relocate it.

[How do I relocate/disable GeckoDriver's log file in selenium, python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109910/how-do-i-relocate-disable-geckodrivers-log-file-in-selenium-python-3http://)

Is there no way to permanently disable it?

Comment: @DyZ that doest seem to be in Python 3. How to make it work in Python 3?

Answer (score 20):

A little late to answer this, but I had the same question just now. I found the solution buried in [this issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/362) on their Github repository. To change the target of the log you can use

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver

# to create a driver with no log
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service_log_path=os.devnull)

# or to just rename the log file
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service_log_path='my-app.log')
```

Initially I got a deprecation warning when I used the keyword argument `log_path` (as suggested in the issue) but that will vary on the version you're using. I'm using `selenium==3.141.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Very (very) late to answering this! But ideally you don't want to use deprecated warnings, because if you update, it could be no longer functional!

I'm using `selenium==4.11.2`, the deprecation warning (as predicted) came true, and you should now use `Service` and `log_output` to change your log files names.

Going off Andrew F's answer (with some additions)

```py
from os import devnull
from selenium import webdriver

# Get rid of geckodriver.log by outputting to /dev/null
service = webdriver.firefox.service.Service(log_output=devnull)

# Initialize driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

That way you don't get deprecation warnings,

Source: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.html