# How to configure GeckoDriver with log level and log location through Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

I am new to python,I writed a program to collect information for me(python+selenium+geckodriver+firefox),everything worked fine,but geckodriver.exe generated too much log,sometimes the single file size of geckodriver.log even reached 8GB.

I searched over galaxy and google and stackoverflow,I can not find an solution to disable geckodriver.log,[this question similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109910/how-do-i-relocate-disable-geckodrivers-log-file-in-selenium-python-3),I know use some parameter could decrease log

```
geckodriver.exe --log fatal
```

And I know python could assign path of geckodriver

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\geckodriver.exe')
```

Is it possible to combine them together?like below:

```
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\geckodriver.exe --log fatal')
```

I tried but failed,Can anyone help me?thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21688906/8150371

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While working with *Selenium v3.14.0 Python Client* to *reduce the logs generated by GeckoDriver* and redirect the logs to a specific *log file* you can use the following solution:

- Using `service_log_path`:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe', service_log_path='./Logs/geckodriver_service_log_path.log')
  ```
- Using `log_path`:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe', log_path='./Logs/geckodriver_log_path.log')
  ```
- To configure the *Log Level* and incorporate the *log path* you can use the following solution:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Log

  log = Log()
  log.level = "TRACE"
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument(log.level)
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe', service_log_path='./Logs/geckodriver_service_log_path.log')
  # driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe', log_path='./Logs/geckodriver_log_path.log')
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  print(driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```

Comment: I am going to have a try,Thanks a lot,too

Answer (score 1):

If you refer the Firefox options object documentation you can see that log is a property of this object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/firefoxOptions

so you can add this as

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

options.log.level = "TRACE"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

you can also set this as :

```
options.set_capability("moz:firefoxOptions", {'log': {'level': 'TRACE'}})
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

**you can use above answer to log to a specific path else the log is created as gekodriver.log in the same directory where your gekodriver is present**

Answer (score 0):

I think setting your service_log_path='' to nothing turns off the log. I could be wrong but I don't seem to have a log file and that's the setting I use.  Anyways, I got tired of typing...

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(service_log_path='')
```

(I used that setting because I kept getting an error every time I tried to specify a PATH.) So I went into the folder...

```
C:\Users\current-user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox
```

Then I found the file service.py and on line 25-26 I removed geckodriver.log from...

```
    def __init__(self, executable_path, port=0, service_args=None,
             log_path="geckodriver.log", env=None):
```

That didn't fix my issue so I went into the file webdriver.py in the same folder on line 53 and removed geckodriver.log from...

```
service_log_path="geckodriver.log", firefox_options=None,
```

and bam now I don't have to set service_log_path to nothing anymore.  But, maybe if you set your log path to service_log_path="" there it will fix your issue.  Not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for but it fixed my problem.  I don't seem to have a log file at all let alone an 8gb sized one.

Comment: Modifying the source code of third-party libraries is not a good idea. What happens when you update selenium and all your changes are overwritten?