# Disable web driver logs in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a script that uses Selenium with Python. When I run the script, it creates a log file in the script directory. When I use the Firefox driver, a `geckodriver.log` file is created.

Is there an option to set to disable this?

Comment: you can set the log file to null for the firefox driver instance.  (also love your name/picture) check out `log_file:`. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.service

Comment: I guess this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109910/how-do-i-relocate-disable-geckodrivers-log-file-in-selenium-python-3